# How do I set the max value if dataframe row to 1 and the rest of the values to 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Original dataframe:

```
ix x  y  z    
0  3  4  1 
1  2  0  6
2  7  1  0
3  0  0  0
```

Should transform into:

```
ix x  y  z    
0  0  1  0 
1  0  0  1
2  1  0  0
3  0  0  0
```

As you can see, i'm taking the max value in each row and setting that equal to 1 then the other values in that row will be equal to 0. Also, you'll notice that row `3` stays the same since they are all equal to 0.

So, I've been able to extract the index of the max value using:

```
x.idxmax(axis = 1)
```

But i'm not sure what to do with the max indices. I'm thinking to use np.where but there isn't a conditional statement I can use. Or so I think.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your logic? What have you tried? It would be great if you can talk about the logic of your transformation and also what approach have you tried to achieve the output.

Comment: I added more details

Comment: What should happen if there are two (or more) maximums in a row?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I'd set them each of the max columns to 1

Comment: Question what do you want to do if the max value in a row is non-zero has two occurances?  IE Row 5 is [4,0,4]  What do you want to return on this row?  [1,0,1]?

Comment: @ScottBoston: Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df.eq(df.where(df != 0).max(1), axis=0).astype(int)
```

where df,

```
      x    y    z
ix               
0   3.0  4.0  1.0
1   2.0  1.0  6.0
2   7.0  1.0  6.0
3   0.0  0.0  0.0
4   4.0  0.0  4.0
```

Output:

```
    x  y  z
ix         
0   0  1  0
1   0  0  1
2   1  0  0
3   0  0  0
4   1  0  1
```

Another method use `rank`:

```
df.where(df!=0).rank(1, ascending=False, method='dense').eq(1).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
    x  y  z
ix         
0   0  1  0
1   0  0  1
2   1  0  0
3   0  0  0
4   1  0  1
```

Answer (score 4):

First, locate the part of the dataframe that has non-zero rows. Then find the maximal values and compare them to the matrix:

```
affected = (df != 0).any(axis=1)
nz = df[affected]
df[affected] = (nz.T == nz.max(axis=1)).T.astype(int)
#    x  y  z
#0   0  1  0
#1   0  0  1
#2   1  0  0
#3   0  0  0
```

Comment: The last row contains two ones?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry. Fixed.

Comment: I updated the solution to take care of your non-zero row requirement.

Answer (score 1):

A rather inelegant way to do it is the following:

```
(df.T.max() == df.T).T.astype(int)
```

Here we calculate the *rowwise* maximum, and then compare it with the values (to set these to `True`/`False`), next we convert it to `int`s.

This generates:

```
>>> (df.T.max() == df.T).T.astype(int)
   a  b  c
0  0  1  0
1  0  0  1
2  1  0  0
```

The `.T` is necessary, since this will otherwise calculate the *columnwise* maximum.

Or like @AChampion says, we can calculate the *rowwise maximum* with `.max(axis=1)` and then use `df.eq(..)` to calculate the equality rowwise as well. Like:

```
>>> df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0).astype(int)
   a  b  c
0  0  1  0
1  0  0  1
2  1  0  0
```

**EDIT**: updating only non-zero rows

We can for example use masking to prevent assigning such values to zero-rows. For example:

```
fl = (df != 0).any(axis=1)
df[fl] = df[fl].eq(df[fl].max(axis=1), axis=0).astype(int)
```

For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[3, 4, 1], [2, 1, 6], [7, 1, 6], [0, 0, 0]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])
>>> fl = (df != 0).any(axis=1)
>>> df[fl] = df[fl].eq(df[fl].max(axis=1), axis=0).astype(int)
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  0  1  0
1  0  0  1
2  1  0  0
3  0  0  0
```

Comment: `df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0).astype(int)`?

Comment: Thank you, now this isn't included in the original question, but say all of the values in my row are the same, in this case I'd prefer to set all of the values to 0.

Comment: @madsthaks: but your comment says 1?

Comment: Let me rephrase, if all of the values are 0, then they should be left as 0.

Comment: @madsthaks: the original values? Can you edit your question with some examples?

Comment: Added more detail to the question. Take a look at row 3. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Hi I think I gave a poor example. I apologize. Please see my update. There may be instances where we see zeros in other rows as well.

Comment: @madsthaks: well if you only want to ignore 0-rows, then this should work with `.any()`. Can you post some rows that are still not working?